# Complexity of single loop that changes its index

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

Can someone please explain how to evaluate the complexity of the following code? Consider that the array_of_size_n is made of positive random numbers in ascending order.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    temp = array_of_size_n[i] + last

    if(temp > last){
        do_something_else(temp); //doesn't change the complexity
        last = temp;
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is a positive element in the array, the iteration will never get past it. What is the time complexity of an endless loop?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that part. There is no negative element in the array. I edited the question adding that info. Thanks!

Comment: How will it ever get past i=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test the growth is linear with a huge constant factor.
Assume last is 0 in the beginning.
It will always pass the first value because the i++ in the loop. 
So when it comes to the second value, if it is 1, then last will be added to INT_MAX. Then if(temp > last) will be false forever, hence linear.
The size of the second value will affect how fast last reach INT_MAX.